# How to show message when last command on button clicked?

Tags: c#, button, messagebox

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] year = { "Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 3", "Year 4", "Year 5", "Year 6", "Year 7", "Year 8", "Year 9", "Year 10" };
    static int y = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    // the code for the progressBar in nextButton_Click was taken from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/745453/Visual-Basic-Progress-Bar-control
    private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.PerformStep();
        yearLabel.Text = year[y];
        y = y + 1;
    }
}
```

at the moment when I click "Next" button it reaches "year 10" thereafter shows error message (An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe).

I want to be able to click the Next button after year 10 and it show a message e.g year 10 complete, end of game etc. Any help would be appreciated on how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the statement _if_?

Comment: Hit: use `if` to check `y` compared to `year.Length`.

Answer (score 2):

We **strongly** recommend you to cover at least the C# basics and read some tutorials about it.

- [if-else statement documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx)
- [C# Operators documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)

**Sample:**

```
if (y != year.Length)        
{       
    progressBar1.PerformStep();
    yearLabel.Text = year[y];
    y = y + 1;               
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("year 10 complete");
}
```

or visa versa

```
if (y == year.Length)            
{
    MessageBox.Show("year 10 complete");          
}
else
{
    progressBar1.PerformStep();
    yearLabel.Text = year[y];
    y = y + 1;
}
```

Comment: This makes me want to delete my answer. Good one haha